# Interim analysis and CI

Tags: clinical-trials, sequential-analysis

A trial was planned and designed to be a single arm trial (one group), and the sample size was calculating using a confidence interval to achieve some accuracy in the estimation of the unknown parameter. For example, a sample size of 30 will allow that the distance between the unknown parameter and the estimate will be no more than 5. Now there is a request for an interim analysis - an early analysis before the trial is over and all the patients has been enrolled.  In hypothesis testing, this inflates the significance level, and the sample size should be adjusted. How will this affect the accuracy of the estimation with a CI and how should I adjust the sample size for it ?